# array in align environment

Tags: arrays

LaTex produces the formula I want:

[image]

but it returns some warning messages. The is the code of the formula above, I don't know where is the mistake:

```
\begin{align}
\mathbb{D} (k,n) = \frac{2}{n_q} ~\text{cos} \bigg(\frac{(n-1)(k-1)\pi}{n_q /2} \bigg) \cdot 
\left\{ \begin{array}{c l l}
1/2 &  \mbox{if} & n=\{1, n_q /2+1 \}\\
1   & \multicolumn{2}{l}{\mbox{otherwise}} \\
\end{array} \right
\end{align}
```

Comment: It should be `\right.` (with a period after `\right`). Also it should be `\cos` and not `\text{cos}`.

Comment: Use `\cos` instead of `\text{cos}` and `\text` instead of `\mbox`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}

\begin{align}
    \mathbb{D} (k,n) = \frac{2}{n_q} ~\cos \bigg(\frac{(n-1)(k-1)\pi}{n_q /2} \bigg) 
    \cdot 
    \begin{cases} 
        1/2 &  \text{if } n=\{1, n_q /2+1 \}\\
        1   & \text{otherwise} \\
    \end{cases}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]